# AWS EC2 - get information on an instance boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Just like we have ec2.describe_instances, is there a method to get the attributes of an instance, by providing the instance-id in boto3?

Answer (score 0):

The [`describe_instances()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) call accepts a list of `InstanceId` values:

```py
response = client.describe_instances(InstanceIds=['i-abcd1234'])
```